# Increasing Function bounded below by a polynomious

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Suppose $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a cotinuous increasing function with $g(0)=0$. Is it possible to find two constants $C>0$ and $q>0$ such that $$g(s)\geq Cs^q,\ \forall\ s\in [0,\delta)$$

where $\delta>0$ is an small number.

Thank you.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot one hypothesis.

Comment: On which ultra common functions did you test your conjecture?

Comment: @Did, what do you have in mind?

Comment: Nothing to add to my first comment: surely you tested your conjecture on some functions, which ones?

Comment: It was clear for me that no polynomious could be a counter example, and that the function must go to zero more fast than any polynomious. THen I got stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still not true. Recall the classical example of a smooth non-zero function with all Taylor coefficients vanishing at 0 (you can construct it with $e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and 0 otherwise).

The Taylor Young theorem says that you won't be able to find such constants for that function.

Comment: addendum : note that your claim stand if you assume the function to be analytical near 0

Comment: Thank you. That's the example I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

No,. this need not be true. One simple way it could fail is if $g$ is bounded (since $Cs^q$ is unbounded). So for example $g(s)=\arctan(s)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one hypothesis, I edited it.